# How can I turn two for loops into one so that joblib can be used?

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, joblib

`func` is a complex function.

I have two for loops, how can I turn `two` for loops into `one` so that `joblib` can be used?

Code show as below:

```
def func(a, b):
    print(a, b)


s1 = range(4)
d2 = range(5)
for s in s1:
    for d in d2:
        func(s, d)
```

Comment: Vectorization depends on the function you want to use. I doubt `print()` is what you actually need. Can you give an example somewhat closer to what you are actually doing?

Comment: @Feodoran func is a complex function. If it can’t be vectorized, can I only use `joblib` to compute in parallel? If I use `joblib`, how can I turn `two` for loops into `one`?

Comment: Without knowing the function I can't tell if it indeed cannot be vectorized. For parallel excecution `joblib` might be an option, or `threading` of the standard library.

Comment: @Feodoran I revised my question, and I think my fuction cannot be vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two for loops, how can I turn two for loops into one so that joblib can be used?

You can "merge" multiple loops into a single one by combining the iterators using the `itertools` module.

```
from itertools import product
s1 = range(4)
d2 = range(5)
for i in product(s1, d2):
   # i is know equivalent to your (s, d)
   print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need.